# Уточняющая конструкция или однородные члены?

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения, однородные-члены

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться со следующим предложением:

Рыболовство было для жителей деревни важным, часто основным(,) источником существования.

Нужна ли запятая после слова "основным"? Конструкцию "часто основным" можно рассмотреть как уточняющую, тогда запятая нужна. А можно посчитать однородной со словом "важным". И тогда, наверное, не нужна запятая.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта, авторский выбор:

А) Рыболовство было для жителей деревни важным, часто основным источником существования..

Однородные определения, сближенные признаки, одна тема (важным, основным), второе определение имеет при себе наречие, которое корректирует его значение.

Пример: Мы вошли в холодный, всю зиму нетопленный зал.

Б) Рыболовство было для жителей деревни важным, часто основным, источником существования. 
Уточняющее определение, сужение значение.

Пример: Он приобрел старую, датированную концом XVIII века, картину.

Answer (score 2):

> Рыболовство было для жителей деревни важным, часто основным(,)
>   источником существования.

Лучше, на мой взгляд, читалось бы с союзом "и".

Варианты:

1. ***Рыболовство было для жителей деревни важным и часто***/зачастую **основным источником существования.**
2. ***Рыболовство было для жителей деревни важным (и часто***/зачастую **основным) источником существования.**

Comment: Важным и основным.

Comment: _V.V.: Важным и основным._ === Нет, не "важным и основным", а "важным и **зачастую** основным".

Answer (score 0):

"Основной" -- уточнение в данном случае и требует после себя запятую. "Основной" имеет значение "самый важный", а (по Розенталю ) уточнение – переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому.